# C2440: Невозможно преобразовать const char* в PVOID

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, указатели

Пишу программу-шутника, который будет менять изображение рабочего стола:
В одной из строчек кода возникла ошибка:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "sr2.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

В третьем аргументе компилятор ругается на то, что невозможно преобразовать const char* в PVOID. Кажется я где-то что то упустил. В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Я в winapi не спец, но возможно из-за того, что Вы пытаетесь указатель на const присвоить указателю на не const

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формально функция `SystemParametersInfo` может менять данные, на которые указывает третий параметр, раз это не указатель на `const`.

Так что формально следует поступить так:

```
char fn[] = "sr2.jpg";
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, fn, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

Но, откровенно говоря, сомневаюсь, что он такое будет чудить, так что, думаю, на практике можно обойтись приведением типа

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, PVOID("sr2.jpg"), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

но этого я вам не говорил! :)

Comment: Еще вопрос, эта функция работает не совсем корректно, вместо нужного изображения становится черный экран) Не могли бы Вы помочь?)

Comment: Ну, я когда-то игрался, но у меня `*.jpg` так и не пошел, пришлось `*.bmp` ему подсовывать. Я тогда не стал разбираться, что да почему. Кстати, если вы разберетесь - скажите, как... :)

Comment: Там оказывается нельзя использовать `jpg`, только `bmp` - шники. В общем, шутник из меня некудышный ))

Comment: Ну, можно конвертить jpg в bmp "на лету"...